# Laravel 4 in subfolder without "public" in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 app which is working fine locally on XAMPP.

I have uploaded it to a domain - domain.com - (hosted with godaddy) and placed it in the *hcr* folder.

In *hcr/app/config/app.php* I have

*'url' => 'http://domain.com/hcr',*

In *hcr/public/.htaccess* I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /hcr

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in the *hcr/.htaccess* I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /hcr
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

to remove *public* from the url.

I can access http://domain.com/hcr/ and the page loads (without styles, images, ...).
But all the other links to pages, images, css, js, ... are wrong.
For example, they link to

*http://domain.com/css/styles.css*

instead of linking to

*http://domain.com/hcr/css/styles.css*

i.e., "hcr" is missing from all the links.

If I go to

*http://maintimeline.com/hcr/public/*

everything is working fine, but I have "public" in the url, which I want to remove.

So, how can I remove "public" from the url with the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these easy steps

```
1. move all files from public directory to root /laravel/ now, no need of public directory, so optionally you can remove it now
2. now open index.php and make following replacements

require DIR.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

 to

 require DIR.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

 and

 $app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

 to

 $app = require_once DIR.'/bootstrap/start.php';

 3. now open bootstrap/paths.php and change public directory path:
 'public' => DIR.'/../public',

 to

 'public' => DIR.'/..',
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's another solution to get rid of the "public" folder from the url. I'm aware of that. But that's not what I was looking for. I wanted to have it working with the .htaccess file and understand why it's not working right now...